# Elixir "Losing" Processes

Tags: elixir

If I create a file `loop.exs`:

```
Enum.each(1..40000, fn (n) -> spawn fn -> IO.puts(n) end end)
```

And run it, counting the lines of output:

```
elixir loop.exs | wc -l
```

And on subsequent runs, I may see the expected `40000` lines, but I might see less. In my tests, I've seen `39752`, `39934`, `39673`, etc. This suggests to me that certain processes aren't getting to call `IO.puts`, so what is happening to them, why aren't I warned they've gone missing, and what am I doing wrong that is making this happen?

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that the script is exiting as soon as it's done evaluating the expressions at the root level. Since spawning processes is asynchronous, Elixir quits as soon as it's done spawning the 40,000th process. The number of lines you're seeing is the number of processes that finished executing `IO.puts` before the 40,000th process was spawned. You can verify this by adding a little `:timer.sleep/1` call at the end:

```
Enum.each(1..40000, fn (n) -> spawn fn -> IO.puts(n) end end)
:timer.sleep(500)
```

With this, I always get 40k lines of output. (This number will be less if the last `IO.puts` isn't executed within 500 milliseconds of the last process being spawned.)

Comment: @Fuser97381 this is the perfectly valid answer and you might discuss your avatar preferences with your roommates. Here on SO you are obliged to mark the question as correct as soon as it is correct. I flagged your comment for moderators’s attention.